# MacOS XAMPP com.apple.quarantine This resource fork intentionally left blank error

Tags: macos, mac, development, php, wordpress

```
Mac OS X  2��ATTR��9�9com.apple.quarantine0081;6444d633;Chrome;BF5ADFCA-C1AF-473E-A86B-31137A883614This resource fork intentionally left blank ��
```

I have set up a localhost WordPress development on my Mac using XAMPP. When I go to the `localhost` using Chrome I get the above error in the header. I have tried deleting `._` files but that did not help.

How do I get rid of the error? I have tried searching for the solution but mine seems to be different.

Comment: Did you remove the **com.apple.quarantine** extended attribute from your files?